# Angular CLI dependencies - why do I need to install @angular/router if I don't use it?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I start a blank Angular CLI project, these dependencies from package.json look like not necessary, so I'm trying to remove them (as well as removing FormModules and HttpModules from imports):

```
@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
```

But when I try build the project, I'm getting an error:

'ERROR in Could not resolve module @angular/router'

And what looks even more weird to me, after re-saving a file the project rebuilds successfully and it works.

Can somebody explain where is this hidden dependency from @angular/router?

My files:

app.modules.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';    
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<h1>test</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular cli uses `@ngtool/webpack` plugin that uses private API from `@angular/compiler-cli` to get lazy loaded routes

**plugin.ts**

```
const {__NGTOOLS_PRIVATE_API_2} = require('@angular/compiler-cli');
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v1.0.1/packages/%40ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.ts#L7

```
// We need to run the `listLazyRoutes` the first time because it also navigates libraries
// and other things that we might miss using the findLazyRoutesInAst.
let discoveredLazyRoutes: LazyRouteMap = this.firstRun ?
__NGTOOLS_PRIVATE_API_2.listLazyRoutes({
  program: this._program,
  host: this._compilerHost,
  angularCompilerOptions: this._angularCompilerOptions,
  entryModule: this._entryModule
})
: this._findLazyRoutesInAst();
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v1.0.1/packages/%40ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.ts#L492-L501

Notice `this.firstRun`.That's why you are getting the error on the first run.

**@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.ts**

```
const ROUTER_MODULE_PATH = '@angular/router';
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.1.0/packages/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.ts#L20

Here is reproduction

[image]

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5967